# How can I add a delete button to an input display using only javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, input, removechild

Okay, before I ask my question, I have searched high and low for this answer and I've only come up with no-ended answers or jQuery answers.
I am trying to do this using JAVASCRIPT ONLY. No other libraries.

I know I'm on the right track, but I just can't figure out how to delete only the last entry of an input that I have created inside a div (all using js).
So, how do I make a delete button actually delete only the input entry it is attached to?

I put my script in a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/vovawotuqe/edit?html,output).
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance! (:

I guess I'm supposed to add my code here anyway so here it is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

Name: <input type="text" id="myText" value="">
<br/>
<br/>
Age: <input type="number" name="age">

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>

function myFunction() {
    var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
    var agenum = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[1].value;
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.border = '2px solid red';
    div.style.padding = '10px';
    div.style.display = 'block';
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    var output = 'Name: ' + input + '<br/>' + 'Age: ' + agenum;
    div.innerHTML = output;
    deleteButton(div);
}

function deleteButton(x) {
    var del = document.createElement('button');
    del.style.textDecoration = 'none';
    del.innerHTML = 'Remove this person?';
    del.style.color = 'white';
    del.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
    document.body.appendChild(del);
}


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: there are 2 options. You are passing DIV to deleteButton() as parameter x, Either put your button inside that x div so you can delete the parent div. OR save the reference to x in your delete button so it can use it for deletion.

Comment: @NawedKhan Oh okay so instead of having a deleteButton(x) function, I should just add the delete button information INSIDE the myFunction?

Comment: @NawedKhan I just still don't understand how to delete the input itself. What would I use for that? .remove or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you dont know is how to remove the div itself, you need to pass it to your deleteButton function and use `removeChild` to delete it. Similar to the delete button itself, `this` is a keyword here.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

Name: <input type="text" id="myText" value="">
<br/>
<br/>
Age: <input type="number" name="age">

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>

function myFunction() {
  
    var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
    var agenum = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[1].value;
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.border = '2px solid red';
    div.style.padding = '10px';
    div.style.display = 'block';
    document.body.appendChild(div);
  
    var output = 'Name: ' + input + '<br/>' + 'Age: ' + agenum;
    div.innerHTML = output;
    
    //create your delete button after you click try it
    var del = document.createElement('button');
    del.style.textDecoration = 'none';
    del.innerHTML = 'Remove this person?';
    del.style.color = 'white';
    del.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
    //assign a function for it when clicked
    del.onclick = function() { deleteButton(div,this)}; 
    document.body.appendChild(del);
   <!--  deleteButton(div);  --> 
}

function deleteButton(x,y) {
   
    var parent = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
    //remove the div
    parent.removeChild(x);
    //remore the button
    parent.removeChild(y);
    
}


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is exactly what I meant by trying to figure out how to delete using .removeChild() you are awesome thanks again!! (:

Answer (score 0):

You're definitely on the right track. The easiest thing to do would be to add an event handler

`del.addEventListener('click', function(){ x.parentNode.removeChild(x); })`

You'll also want to make sure you delete the button though, but I'm sure you can get that figure that out. Also here's great resource for converting jQuery to vanilla JS http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Comment: Hey thanks man! I'm definitely gonna be checking out that site lol I love jQuery but I'm trying to see how good I can be with just vanilla you know? Appreciate it!